# Scroll page on page load if at top of page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to do something if the page is detected to be at the very top of the page otherwise don't do it. I'm guessing I need to use and if statement somehow but I'm just not sure how to do this.

For example, I want the page to scroll to 125 pixels if the page is at the very top otherwise don't scroll to that position.

$('html, body').animate({scrollTop:125}, 4000);

Comment: Have you some UpdatePanel inside the page?

Comment: Not sure I'm following you. I want this all to occur on page load such as inside of a $(window).load(function(){

Comment: Basically I think I need to write an if statement that if top of page is detected then fire $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:125}, 4000); else don't fire it.

Answer (score 0):

Use this on load:

```
function checkTop(){
    if ($(window).scrollTop() == 0) {
        $(window).animate({scrollTop:125}, 4000);
    }
}

checkTop();

$(window).scroll(function(){
    checkTop();
})
```